# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '`default`' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `fastimporter_attributes`

Tags: mysql, sql, database, magento, magento-1.9

I am getting below error on magento1.9, How can I solve this one.

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '`default`' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `fastimporter_attributes` AS `main_table` WHERE (`profile_id` = '8') AND (`default` IS NOT NULL)

Comment: is this a custom query or auto-generated by the framework?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this command:

```
SELECT main_table.* FROM fastimporter_attributes AS main_table WHERE (profile_id = '8') AND (main_table.default IS NOT NULL)
```

The "default" field is quite sensitive in this case, I think you should use main_table.default

Comment: Hi, I am using below mentioned module and I think the complete database has not been imported. Can anybody help on my db installer file. https://github.com/spletnik/magento_fast_importer

Comment: You need to find out which fields are missing, then add them manually.